# Error when trying to encrypt USB memory with gnome-disks

Tags: partitioning, encryption, gnome-disk-utility

Ubuntu 15.10 + gnome-disks: First I quick-formatted the drive (tried both MBR and GPT). Then I setup EXT+LUKS partition for the whole 32 GB of space, but I immediately get this error dialog when proceeding:

```
Error creating partition

Error wiping newly created partition /dev/sdf1: Command-line `wipefs -a
"/dev/sdf1"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: wipefs: error:
/dev/sdf1: probing initialization failed: No such file or directory
(udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

I was trying to follow these instructions:

http://www.howtogeek.com/115955/how-to-quickly-encrypt-removable-storage-devices-with-ubuntu/

Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used gnome-disks to do that, the guide you linked to is from 2012 & has screenshots of the "old" Disks UI (*better IMO*) but it's not my first choice for these tasks (it is awesome for info & basic mount/umount, unlock/lock LUKS devices).

But I have successfully used Gparted (or just parted) to clear / create a partition (/dev/sdf1 in your example) and then in a terminal:

```
cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdf1
```

and open it with one of these ("old syntax" is listed first, less typing)

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdf1 cryptname
cryptsetup open --type luks /dev/sdf1 cryptname
```

and then format it with

```
mkfs.ext<2,3,4> /dev/mapper/cryptname
```

then mount & use it

```
mount /dev/mapper/cryptname
```

That's if there's not a hardware error on the drive that's causing the wipefs problem. If you can create (or already have) the partition, then LUKS should overwrite everything anyway (or a `dd` with /dev/zero after it's luksOpen-ed). I'd try not using gnome-disks first - fewer things to go wrong.

---

Found a confirmed bug report about the error ([Erasing disk failed: Error wiping newly created partition](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks2/+bug/1460602)) reproducible using Gnome Disks too. Apparently:

> Seems like udisks is trying to act on a device before the device node appears. The affected code seems to live in src/udiskslinuxpartitiontable.c, that pretends to "sit and wait for the partition to show up" before wiping the newly created partition, but apparently doesn't reliably wait for the device node to appear in /dev.

With a [comment for a workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks2/+bug/1460602/comments/3) using `dd` to erase the first MB (MiB) of a partition:

> sudodus (nio-wiklund) wrote on 2015-09-18:     #3
>
> My tip for a solution is independent of waiting for udisks to be fixed:
>
> - Wipe the first megabyte (actually mibibyte) *
>
> When the target drive is identified and selected (so that there can be no mistake), simply wipe the first mibibyte (use dd under the hood to overwrite it with zeros). This has worked well for me and people I have helped at the Ubuntu Forums. It is part of mkusb and I have used and recommended the method for years. mkusb from ppa:mkusb/unstable has a menu with several alternatives, where the first one (standard) will create pendrives, that work with for example the s-d-c and Unetbootin.

The workaround should be equivalent to your just using `cryptsetup` on the partition once it's created, since it shouldn't care if there's an existing filesystem there anyway and warns that it will overwrite any existing data.

Comment: Well, gnome-disks worked perfectly on my 14.04 system for the same USB drive so this must be regression. These kind of things just should work out-of-the-box.

Comment: Added bug report info to answer. Also, at least in the past, Ubuntu has apparently picked the "less tested" versions of Gnome Disks (I think one version a few years ago even described itself as  "Experimental") instead of the stable or "more tested" versions available. One of the risks of Ubuntu using Debian's "testing" instead of "stable"