# LUKS crashes utility, command line doesn't provide encryption, alternative GUI applications are too slow

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, encryption, luks

TLDR: I'm trying to encrypt my hard drive, half of universe failed.

What is a straight-forward command towards encrypting target device (e.g. `/dev/sdb1`) with a "target" password (e.g. "password123"). And being able to unlock it in Linux later with relative ease?

I have a hard drive that I wanted to encrypt. We're talking about 100000 of files and 200GB of data.

I use Linux Ubuntu and the target hard drive is 2TB. I wanted to use LUKS in Disk Utility (**Disks** in Dashboard). However whenever I try to format and encrypt the drive this utility crashes. Here's an image of what I'm trying to use:

[image: dialog window]

Of course this image isn't from Ubuntu but the options are the same and I'm sure it's Linux as well.

With [this query](https://www.google.com/?q=disk%20utility%20crashes%20on%20LUKS%20encryption)

It seems to be a known error:

- [Launchpad bug 1096272](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/+bug/1096272)
- [Launchpad bug 1697232](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/+bug/1697232)

They either update the tracker or add it to "to fix list", but so far no known solution.

[Error when trying to encrypt USB memory with gnome-disks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/745116/error-when-trying-to-encrypt-usb-memory-with-gnome-disks)
Does feature certain command lines, but I don't have/can't find the field or parameter where I need to fill in my password.

There is a "workaround" posted on the internet, which explains something about udisk trying to access something that doesn't exist. The workaround is to "delete the first 1 mibibyte of the flash drive". But upon looking for it through [this query](https://www.google.com/?q=erase%20first%201mb%20dd)

The first link says:
"linux - Wipe last 1MB of a Hard drive"
and no other link has anything to do with devices. It's all about files and stuff that doesn't help my cause.

I thought to myself, maybe there's alternate ways to encrypt, but nothing "easy-to-use" appears, always LUKS tutorials, all of which don't work. So I thought maybe a graphical interface, maybe just the utility is broken, maybe other applications will try different ways that aren't broken, so I tried [searching for LUKS GUI](https://www.google.com/?q=LUKS%20GUI)

And found [luckyLUKS on GitHub](https://github.com/jas-per/luckyLUKS)

I installed luckyLUKS and it looked fantastic, until I discovered that LuckyLUKS needs to claim entire drive, and "initialize" it all the way through. It took LuckyLUKS 2 minutes to initialize 1% of 16GB USB. But my main target is usage of 2TB. I have to go in two days and I need my drive encrypted (with its content) by then.

Also on GitHub, [cryptsetup-gui](https://github.com/jonhoo/cryptsetup-gui) is only meant for "unlocking" cryptsetup.

zuluCrypt and veraCrypt seem plausible, however site and application possess no verifiable history, and I don't feel safe entrusting my personal data as well as root access to a random application. Although in last resort I may install it.

And this is some 4th day that I'm scanning the web for a solution or alternative program. To no avail.

I barely know anything about Linux commands themselves and my programming skills aren't at near par to fix the source code. I know how command lines work, but that's about it.

At that point I'm not interesting at fixing this bug any more, I'm more focused on getting my drive safely encrypted and I'm on short time of two days.

*Note, when Googling I used more than a single query, I used multiple wordings from the same query.*

Comment: You're using all sorts of custom, non-standard tools.  I'm not sure that AskUbuntu is the right place for help, but instead you should work with the people providing the software, and read the documentation they provide.  Really, I suggest you use standard tools, and recommended and documented Ubuntu software.  Please see [this list of documents](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystems).

Comment: @earthmeLon Disk utility is part of standard Ubuntu, it's called "Disks".

Comment: Did you try to use `cryptsetup` directly? See the section on “Block-level encryption” in [this answer](/a/688828/175814) but with whatever block device you want to use instead of the image files used in the question. You can use those for tests of course. If that works and roughly suits your needs I'll write a slightly adapter answer to your question.